# How should exactly the brake cable be fixed to V-brake caliper?

Tags: brakes, safety, cable, rim-brake

Regarding the V-brake calipers, where the cable is tightened with a screw:

Should the cable go between the head of the screw and the washer (1), or should it go between the screw head and the body of the brake caliper (2)? And most importantly, why? (Is either of the two dangerous, e.g. could the cable slip or break?)

(1) Cable between the head of the screw and the washer:

[image: cable between the head of the screw and the washer]

(2) Cable between the head of the screw and the body of the brake:

[image: cable between screw and brake]

Comment: Your second option looks like it might slip without warning. Normally, a washer with an obvious groove is included.

Comment: So this means the first one is the correct one?

Comment: No, I do not think it is.

Comment: Ok, after reading JoeK's answer, I think I get your point: the second option is the correct one, but the cable is not seated deep enough.

Answer (score 7):

Picture 2 is correct. The washer should prevent the cable being damaged or pulled by tightening the bolt.

However, on some cheaper brakes the bolt and washer are such poor quality that they turn together and the benefit is lost.

I will add that your cable in picture 2 isn't seated deeply enough behind the washer.

[image]

Note that i usually leave more cable and tuck it away behind the spring. This photo is OK for reference to clamping though.

Comment: When would it be seated deeply enough? If the top of the cable was not visible at all? Or does it need to cover the side too?

Comment: @Attilo The cable should follow a straight path and is usually completely hidden at 12 o'clock on the washer. If you take out the bolt you will usually see there is a groove in the brake arm for the cable on most brakes of this type.

Comment: And should it be hidden *only* at 12 o'clock, and then stick out (like in the picture), or is it better if it does a half turn and gets hidden from 12 o'clock to 3 o'clock?

Comment: +1 good spot on the cable too

Comment: On many V-brake calipers there's a groove directed in a generally  vertical direction or with a slight angle from inside (top) to outside (bottom).  Seating the cable in this groove and securing it beneath the washer helps generate the proper leverage on the caliper arm (the downward direction the cable follows makes a little hook or loop around the pinch bolt.  This is good to secure the cable better, preventing slip, and puts the pulling force of the cable at and around the solid pinch bolt. Also, excess inner brake cable is directed down toward where you can seat it behind the lever arm.

Comment: The cable that is hidden between 12 and 2 behind the washer is likely in the intended fixing position of the caliper arm.